# OpenGL shader getting incorrect data even though it seems correct

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, opengl-3

I just started learning how to use OpenGL 3.2, and right now I am trying to put together a utility for loading geometry data. When I look at the code for loading in the vertices, everything looks correct, and the debug output I put in even seems to be giving me the correct values. The code should be producing a single triangle with each point getting full r, g, or b, but is instead getting almost pure red/orange.

Here is the code with the geometry data:

```
    final float[] vertexPositions3 = new float[] {
            0.0f,    0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.366f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.366f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    };

    geometry = new Geometry();
    geometry.addBufferOffset(vertexPositions3, GL_STATIC_DRAW, 0, Geometry.VERTEX_4F, Geometry.VERTEX_4F);
```

And the code that loads it:

```
protected int getDataTypeSize(int dataType) {
    if(dataType == VERTEX_1F) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(dataType == VERTEX_2F) {
        return 2;
    }
    else if(dataType == VERTEX_3F) {
        return 3;
    }
    else {
        return 4;
    }
}

public void addBufferOffset(float[] data, int usage, int vertexColumn, int... dataTypes) {
    if(numAttributes + dataTypes.length >= MAX_VBO) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can only have up to 16 attributes, requested: " + (numAttributes + dataTypes.length));
    }

    int rowSize = 0;
    for(int type : dataTypes) {
        rowSize += getDataTypeSize(type);
    }
    if(numRows == 0) {
        numRows = data.length / rowSize;
    }
    else if(numRows != (data.length / rowSize)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Number of rows in buffers don't match: " + numRows + " vs " + (data.length / rowSize));
    }

    if(numVertices == 0) {
        numVertices = getDataTypeSize(dataTypes[0]) * (data.length / rowSize) / getDataTypeSize(dataTypes[0]);
    }
    else {
        int addingVerts = getDataTypeSize(dataTypes[0]) * (data.length / rowSize);
        if(addingVerts != numVertices) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Vertex count for buffers don't match: " + numVertices + " vs " + addingVerts);
        }
    }
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    FloatBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
    buf.put(data);
    buf.flip();
    int vbo = glGenBuffers();
    vbos[numBuffers++] = vbo;
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf, usage);

    int startPos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dataTypes.length; i++) {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(numAttributes + i);
        glVertexAttribPointer(numAttributes + i, getDataTypeSize(dataTypes[i]), GL_FLOAT, false, 0, startPos);
        System.out.println((numAttributes + i) + ", " + getDataTypeSize(dataTypes[i]) + ", " + startPos);
        startPos += numRows * getDataTypeSize(dataTypes[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Num verts: " + numVertices);
    if(usesIndices) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesRef);
    }
    numAttributes += dataTypes.length;
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

And the vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;

smooth out vec4 theColor;
uniform float loopDuration;
uniform float time;
uniform vec4 camera;

void main() {
    float timeScale = 3.14159f * 2.0f / loopDuration;
    vec4 totalOffset = vec4(
        cos(time * 1.5f * timeScale) * 0.5f,
        sin(time * 1.5f * timeScale) * 0.5f,
        0.0f,
        0.0f);
    gl_Position = position + totalOffset;
    theColor = color;
}
```

And finally the fragment shader:

```
#version 330

smooth in vec4 theColor;

out vec4 outputColor;

uniform float fragLoopDuration;
uniform float time;

const vec4 firstColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
const vec4 secondColor = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

void main() {
    float lerpTime = time * 1.5f / fragLoopDuration;
    outputColor = theColor;
}
```

When I run the program, the addBufferOffset method produces the following output:

```
0, 4, 0
1, 4, 12
Num verts: 3
```

Meaning that it found two sets of three vertices with four floating-point values each. One of them starts at array offset 0, and the other starts at array offset 12. This corresponds with the array that is getting sent to it: 3 vertices with x, y, z, w values and 3 vertices with r, g, b, a values. From the output, it seems like it should be working, but it isn't. I would really appreciate some help figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with lwjgl, but the final argument of the OpenGL `glVertexAttribPointer` function in the C API is the byte offset of the data - it seems that you're passing in an array index instead.  This could explain why you see a red/orange triangle because the data starting at the 12th byte (after 3 floats) looks like this:

```
        1.0f, 0.5f, -0.366f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -0.5f, -0.366f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f
```

Clamping these values to be between 0 and 1 will give

```
        1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f
```

Assuming your blend settings are such that you ignore the zero alpha component these will give orange, red and yellow vertices.

Comment: LWJGL has an almost 1 to 1 translation of the C API, with only minor changes (such as not needing a length for a FloatBuffer, because the length is stored in the object). The byte offset being incorrect was absolutely correct, thank you SO much. I just had to multiply the index by 4 and everything worked. I was tearing my hair out about this for a bit.